# How to serialize a multiple list of elements in Json?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "Identifier1":"TextOfIdentifier1",
    "Identifier2":"TextOfIdentifier2",
    "Identifier3":"TextOfIdentifier3",
    ...
}
```

I know how to deseralize a JSON into a custom object, I followed what says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620173/760893), but all identifiers appear in the same JSON tag...

How can I get all identifiers inside the JSON?

Comment: The first option in linked answer is ["LINQ to JSON"](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm).

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. What do you mean when you say in the same JSON tag? In your example you have different property names

Comment: But it tries to deseralize a custom object... The thing is that my json has all the identifiers in the same json...

Comment: They are like 2000 identifiers. How can I read them without parsing it in a custom object? Only get the left value (identifier) and the right value? (for each line...)

Comment: So you just want to avoid creating a class for all the properties? Sounds like it might be better to break it down somehow, but you could use dynamic too. Like this: `dynamic d = JObject.Parse(jsonstringhere);`

Comment: @rmc00 You'd be still loading all the properties with `dynamic`

Comment: @MatiasCicero I thought the intent was to avoid making a class with all 2000 properties because there's too many or they might change. Maybe Sonhja can clarify... you're thinking that the intent is to not load all properties, i.e. only load some of the properties?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is like this in my case:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path))
{
     string json = r.ReadToEnd();
     JObject jsonLines = JObject.Parse(json);
     foreach (var token in jsonLines)
     {
         dtos.Add(new TokenDto { HalId = token.Key, SourceText = token.Value.ToString() });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse JSON (similar to XDocument):

```
var json = "{\"Identifier1\":\"TextOfIdentifier1\",\"Identifier2\":\"TextOfIdentifier2\",\"Identifier3\":\"TextOfIdentifier3\"}";
foreach (var token in JObject.Parse(json).Children())
    Console.WriteLine(token.Path);
```

Result:

> Identifier1
>
> Identifier2
>
> Identifier3

Comment: I want to get both parts... not only the identifier :P